# Does c# have inner class extra overhead?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following simple class:

```
class Stack {
  public class Node // inner class
  {
      string item;
      Node next;
  }
}
```

A stack with `N` items uses: `8 bytes (reference to String)` + `8 bytes (reference to Node)` + `16 bytes (sync block index + type object pointer)`. But I wonder about inner class overhead. Do I need to add an extra `8 bytes`? So a stack with N items uses ~ 40*N bytes or ~32*N bytes?

Comment: "inner class overhead"? What do you mean by that? What would the extra 8 bytes represent?

Comment: No you needn't because you are already have a reference to the next node (8 bytes in x64 app and 4 bytes fox x86 app).

Comment: As I know in Java inner class have an extra overhead(+8 bytes).

Comment: Right, so `Node` contains another `Node`. I didn't notice this.. Maybe make it more obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# inner classes do not have a hidden reference to an instance of the outer class like `Java` does it. If you want that behavior you can create it manually. There is nothing like that in C#.

An inner class mainly has different access rules and a differently structured name. Also, inner classes share the generic type parameters of the outer class which *might* create overhead. It's mainly an organization concept (in C#).